# how would you create this database?

Tags: php, mysql, backend

I'm trying to create a database to store nearly 5000 records per day (500 per user) and I was wondering if that can slow down the website.

I have an idea to store every 500 data for a user in a text file and save the .txt file into just one row. This way 5000 rows are reduced to 10 rows.

**will this work?**

PS: I will use PHP implode and explode functions to assemble and disassemble the .txt file.

If you can suggest any better ways that will be amazing.

Comment: 5k rows per day, 1.5kk per year - this is small database. Proper indexing and query optimizing will prevent "slow down the website".

Comment: If it slows down your website depends on how you save them, how you select them and the structure of your db (indexes for example). I would even think implode/explode will be slower.

Comment: *I will use PHP implode and explode functions to assemble and disassemble the .txt file.* Study MySQL documentation, LOAD DATA statement. Do not perform data-processing tasks on PHP, database server can do this by more effective way.

Comment: @akina If I use LOAD DATA, I should check for threats before creating the file... That is more confusing for me but good to know I have this option. Thank you.

Comment: ?? what threats? The only threat is incorrect data which can cause incorrect values for some columns for some rows or import aborting in the middle of the process... but you a) may check input data before LOAD DATA b) preprocess loaded data before assigning into the fields.

Answer (score 2):

5000, 50000, 500 000, 5 000 000, *50 000 000* records wont slow your website if you will set indexes right and definitely  using .txt files are not best choice to store the data, just set your table in right way (correct column data type, indexes, good and optimized queries)